# directive parameter issue with angular templateURL

Tags: angularjs

i have following directive

```
App.directive('minuteListDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A,E",
        required: 'ng-model',

        templateUrl: "/app/profile/company-minutes/templates/minute-list.html",
        controller: "CompanyMinutesController",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            mode: '@mode',
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

        },
    }
});
```

when i remove  scope: {
                mode: '@mode',
            },
from directive , the template render correctly as below (minute-list.html )

```
<div dropdown="dropdown" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button dropdown-toggle="" ng-class="'btn btn-default'" class="ng-binding btn btn-default" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <b class="caret"></b> 
    </button>
    <ul role="menu" ng-class="'dropdown-menu animated flipInX'" class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX">
        <li>
            <a href="#" ng-click="update(minute)">edit</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-edit-mode">
            <a href="#" ng-click="delete(minute)">delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but when i add scope: { mode: '@mode'} to directive the template render but it removes  ng-class from rendered template

```
<div dropdown="dropdown" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button dropdown-toggle="" ng-class="''" class="ng-binding" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <b class="caret"></b>operation
    </button>
    <ul role="menu" ng-class="''">
        <li>
            <a href="#" ng-click="update(minute)">edit</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-edit-mode">
            <a href="#" ng-click="delete(minute)">delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is original template without rendering

```
<div dropdown="dropdown" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button dropdown-toggle="" ng-class="'btn btn-default'" class="ng-binding btn btn-default">
        <b class="caret"></b> {{resources.grid.ACTION_BUTTOM_TEXT}}
    </button>
    <ul role="menu" ng-class="'dropdown-menu animated flipInX'" class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX">
        <li>
            <a href="#" ng-click="update(minute)">edit</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-edit-mode">
            <a href="#" ng-click="delete(minute)">delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are using `ng-class` as you are passing `hard-coeded string` to it? It will affect performance as `ng-class` is directive. Angular need to parse and perform action accordingly. You can simply do  `class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX"` in your markup.

Comment: i didn't made this directive i am debugging application , but the issue is not just ng-class , everything inside {{}} will be removed .

Comment: As you are using `isolated scope` by specifying `scope:{}`, `resources` is not available to it.  You can do `scope: {  mode: '@mode', resources: '=' }`. I will also recommend you to use `class` instead of `ng-class` if you are passing just `string`.

Comment: i tried this , didn't solve problem .